# What are these different calendar views?

Tags: calendar

I've got a handful of Events that should appear in the Calendar. When I click the Calendar tab, it is totally empty and looks like the screenshot on the left. When I go to an Activity/Event and click "view availability" next to its start date, it brings me to the view on the right which shows the Events.

What is the difference, and how can I get the latter functionality to be what happens with the Calendar tab?

[image]